# how to get list of attributes from a JSONata query

Tags: jsonata

I want to know for the given JSONata query how can we find out list of attributes with their path. Is there any any API/function to get some metadata about the query. For e.g. for the following query I want to find out the attribute name as "Account.Order.Product.Price" and "Account.Order.Product.Quantity"

```
$sum(Account.Order.Product.(Price * Quantity))
```

This may not be simple Regx or string parsing as query can contain functions & operators as well.

Atul